# Python get a list from a string

Tags: python

I'm getting a json with some items, and one of them can come in a list format inside a string, for example:

```
jsonresp = {
    "number":1,
    "size":17,
    "totalPages":1,
    "numberOfElement":17,
    "totalElements":"17",
    "accounts":"['123', '456', '789']"
}
```

putting the account attribute in a variable, I wanted to receive it in a list format and not a string.
I tried as follows but it doesn't work:

```
accounts = list(jsonresp["accounts"])
```

I managed to do it using replace the characters [ and ], and then doing a comma split, but if there is a string with a comma, I may have problems.
I wanted to know if there was a more direct way to do it.

Comment: Use the `json` module to parse the string into Python structures.

Comment: `literal_eval` from the module `ast` will do that for you.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The string isn't valid JSON; it uses `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: @TheTechRobotheNerd They're claiming it's JSON though. I assumed that was a typo in the example.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I thought they meant that they are receiving JSON from the server, parsing it, and that is where their dict comes from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `ast.literal_eval()`?

```
accounts = ast.literal_eval(jsonresp["accounts"])
```

Sould output:

```
['123', '456', '789']
```